# GIT status missing in Visual Studio Code explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I can clearly the GIT status of files on my current dev machine (Win10).

[image: current dev workstation]

I needed to help update the dev tools on a laptop (Win8.1). VSCode and GIT versions are identical but I can't see the GIT status in the Explorer.

[image: problem laptop]

GIT is definitly working on the laptop; I can clearly see the files statuses in the SCM UI, but I'm missing these in the Explorer.

Is there some old config on the laptop that might be affecting this or is there a setting I'm just missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ensure the following setting is set to `true`:

```json
"git.decorations.enabled": true
```

And then reload the window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and insert *reload window*, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If this does not work you can check whether an extension overwrites this setting.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!

Comment: I went in the settings and searched for "git decorations" thanks to this post, finding the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Note: with VSCode 1.53 (Jan. 2021), you can also see `git status` in the tabs themselves!

> ### [Tab Decorations](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/40e20706acf07af1a987f9185e5a5108cd050fdf/release-notes/v1_53.md#tab-decorations)
>
> Two new settings allow to configure whether editor tabs show decorations, such as `git status` or diagnostics.
>
> - Use `workbench.editor.decorations.colors` to decorate tabs with colors, like red/green for files with error and warning, and
> - use `workbench.editor.decorations.badges` to decorate tabs with badges, like `M` for git modified.
>
> [image: Editor Tab with decorations]
> <sup>Theme: [GitHub Light Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.github-vscode-theme)</sup>